# Unable to install tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this issue. I followed several tutorials. I have installed the CUDA toolkit 11.2, cuDNN 8.1, Python 3.10.11, and Bazelisk. Any suggestions?

No idea what to do. I have been working on this for the past few days.

Comment: This is a bug in tensorflow-gpu.  You should never compare version numbers as strings, because in a string comparison, "3.10" is less than "3.7".  Perhaps there is a fixed version.

Comment: Have you tried installing `tensorflow` instead of `tensorflow-gpu`? I believe they recently renamed the package.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like an issue with the file ***C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging\requirements.py line 3***.  If you can edit it so that it says `python_version>3.7` and rerun the install, do that.

Downgrading to Python3.9 can also fix the issue by avoiding the string comparison problem. I was curious if I could install it using 3.9 on my laptop and it installed fine using python3.9 [python3.9 on my winbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkK5n.png) see the pic for the [pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utF9q.png)

Ideally the install wouldn't test the python version as a string, which appears to be the root cause.